# Dynamically Create a specific div with its children in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I'm sorry in advance if this seems to be a beginners question and wasted some of your time, but it does really bother me and I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

I'm simply creating a "zone" if you will, where the user inputs a word/sentence which are tasks, and then can check if the task was completed or not and/or if the word/sentence needs to be changed.

So in the end, what I need is a textbox lets say where the user inputs a specific number supposed x, and generates x times this div.

Here is the code (unfortunately I could not post pics since I do not have enough reputation..)

**ASP.NET code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="GMode.tiz.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>whatevz</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../functions.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="singleContainer">
            <div class="lblPlace">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Input Task"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="hi" CssClass="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" CssClass="UniversalBtn" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" CssClass="UniversalBtn" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="edit" runat="server" CssClass="UniversalBtn" />
            <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" CssClass="BtnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="DONE"/>
        </div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GMode.tiz
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl.CssClass = "done";
        }

        protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl.CssClass = "undone";
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (hi.Text == "")
            {
                lbl.Text = "No Value";
            }
            else
            {
                lbl.Text = hi.Text;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So basically I want to dynamically create `<div class="singleContainer">` with everything inside it x times (x defined by the user).

I'm going about this more on the fact like it's C++. When you can dynamically create an array with a specific number x.

Please tell me if you need more of the code. There are still the css and js files that I did not post.

Thank you,
Jack

Answer (score 1):

I think that for this the best option is to use AngularJS, you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.change = function (){
$scope.listDivs = [];

    for(var i=0;i<$scope.createDiv;i++) {
      $scope.listDivs.push(i);
    }
}


})
</script>
</head>
   <body ng-app='app'>
   <div ng-controller='PostsCtrl' class='container'>
   <input ng-model='createDiv' ng-change="change()"/>
   <ul class='list-group'>
    <li ng-repeat="post in listDivs" class='list-group-item'>
      <div class="singleContainer">
        <div class="lblPlace">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Input Task">   </asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="hi" CssClass="txtBox" runat="server">   </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" CssClass="UniversalBtn" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" CssClass="UniversalBtn" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="edit" runat="server" CssClass="UniversalBtn" />
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" CssClass="BtnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="DONE"/>
    </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your div into a usercontrol (ascx file).

In your main page add a placeholder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
```

in code behind you can add your control as often as you want:

```
yourControl= LoadControl("~/Controls/yourControl.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(yourControl);
```

Comment: In other words do I change the whole file from asp.net to ascx or just take the div to an ascx file? If it's the second option it means that the placeholder is actually the div right?

Comment: You create a NEW ascx file. Move the Div into the new ascx file, and add the placeholder to your "old" aspx file So there will be just the placeholder instead of the div. Of course you need to move your logic into the ascx file as well.

Comment: Ahh alright...Last question and I'm really sorry if it seems dull... But the specific number that the user inputs, it's in `yourControl` right? How do I specify that?

Comment: Couldn't you do the same thing with a `Panel` control (which renders as a DIV).

Comment: @SteveWellens what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of using `DIVS`, uses `Panels`.   The server code can access the Panels and add controls.

Comment: @SteveWellens could you elaborate a little bit more please? I'm a complete beginner c#

Comment: @SteveWellens I edited it, this should explain more what I'm trying to do